# GIT installation after homebrew reinstall in OSX Yosemite

Tags: git, homebrew, osx-yosemite

After my Yosemite upgrade homebrew was not working. I had to remove the folders manually to reinstall it again. the installation process went fine. Installation of  brew itself is fine.

Now I reinstalled GIT by downloading it using the brew (`brew install git`). It is installed to the directory `/usr/local/bin/git`. However, when I check the installation by checking its version (`git --version`), I get an error: `**/usr/bin/git: No such file or directory**`

I tried changing PATH in my profile to no avail. I have no .bashrc or .bash_profile in my system. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/a/13146463/6309 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/27557519/6309 help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I restarted my terminal, just to check. It worked like a charm...

So, not all installations are directly updating the relevant paths. It is better to restart the terminal before checking if an installation has gone through fine...!

Comment: The first link did include "reinstalling the package, and then quitting and restarting the terminal.", so I was hoping that would help in your case ;)

Comment: Yeah... thats what gave me the idea to restart... Thanks a Lot... VonC